# C: #include error even after placing the header file in the right path

Tags: c, windows, sdl, sdl-2

I've downloaded SDL_mixer, which plays sound. Even tho I placed the `.h` file in the include folder, it's still showing me the error:

```
fatal error: SDL_stdinc.h: No such file or directory
```

Here's the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Modifying your compiler installation is a bad idea. You should either install SDL2 package from `pacman`, OR put the downloaded SDL2 elsewhere and specify the path to it when compiling.

Comment: What compiler do you use? It should be `/mingw64/bin/gcc` from `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` package, not `/usr/bin/gcc` from `gcc` package. If you're compiling from MSYS2 terminal, the terminal has to be launched using `mingw64.exe` to ensure that `/mingw64/bin` is in the PATH (this should put you in [`MINGW64` environment](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/) instead of `MSYS`, as indicated by the magenta text in the terminal prompt).

Comment: Your IDE and your compiler are different beasts. Errors shown in the IDE come from your project's setup.

Comment: Did you notice that the file you placed in include folder is not the file that is reported as missing? Where is that file? You probably should add that folder as include folder to compile options.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @HolyBlackCat I used a `pacman` installer instead of putting the header files manually...

I opened MSYS and typed this command to install SDL:

`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-pkg-config mingw-w64-x86_64-SDL2`

Then I imported it by including SDL by this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <SDL2\SDL_mixer.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

No import errors. Everything worked like a breeze!

Answer (score -2):

I think you should look inside the SDL_mixer.h library.  SDL_stdinc.h may be defined in it.